# IfxDataReader returning null

Tags: c#, .net, informix

when ever I try to execute a query on informix using C#, it gives me this error `{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}`

I'm using :

- Windows 7 Ultimate 64bits
- VS2013 Ultimate
- Informix Client SDK3.50.FC9.WIN

here is my code;

```
string ConnectionString = "Blah;" + "Service=sqlexec;" + "Server=Blah;" + "Database=base004;" + "Uid=me;" + "Pwd=pw;";
IfxConnection conn = new IfxConnection(ConnectionString);
conn.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
try
{
   string resql = "select * from table";                  
   try
   {
       conn.Open();
       MessageBox.Show("Connection open");
       IfxCommand rq = new IfxCommand(resql, conn);
       IfxDataReader dr = rq.ExecuteReader();
       while (dr.Read()) 
       {
           string a = dr.GetString(0);
           int b = dr.GetInt32(1);
           string c = dr.GetString(2);
       }
    }
    catch (IfxException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    conn.Close();
}
catch (IfxException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: As unrelated feedback: I expect that `conn`, `rq` and `dr` are all `IDisposable`, and should *all* be using `using` statements

Comment: @MarcGravell And yes there is a using IBM.Data.Informix;

Comment: @faidam no, you misunderstand me; `using IBM.Data.Informix` is a using *directive*, not a using *statement*; I mean as in: `using(IfxConnection conn = new IfxConnection(ConnectionString)) { ... nested code here ...}`

Comment: With the edit that now removes the `rq` / `cmd` confusion: which line is throwing this exception?

Comment: Also: does `IfxDataReader` *really* have a method called `getInt`? I might have expected `GetInt32`?

Comment: @MarcGravell 
First: the line returning the error is IfxDataReder dr = rq.ExectureReader();
Secondly: yes its GetInt32, I've mist wrote it 
Thirdly: for the using statement, should I put my code as it is between the "{ // my code here?  }"?

Comment: @MarcGravell I've put my code between the { } and still giving me the same error at the same line

Comment: "at the same line" - ***which line***; please tell us which line is throwing the exception

Comment: put the connection within  the using block.

Comment: @marcGravell at the line where IfxDataReader dr = rq.ExecuteReader();

Comment: @karthikeyan it didn't help :(

Comment: @faidam k; there's nothing *shown* that should cause that error; do you have the `StackTrace`?

Comment: @marcgravell what is its? Where can I find it?

Comment: @faidam when you catch an exception `ex`, it is `ex.StackTrace`

Comment: @MarcGravell So sorry guys, I've been off the past couple of days.
when here is exectly what I get when I run the winform [link](http://p1.pichost.me/640/73/1975525.jpg)

Comment: @faidam Sony RIC killer? I fail to see the relevance...

Comment: @MarcGravell dump error, I've uploaded the wrong pic [link] (http://p1.pichost.me/i/73/1975996.jpg)

Comment: @faidam right; click "view detail", which should present the usual object expando view; now locate the StackTrace member.

Comment: @MarcGravell here what it says [link](http://p1.pichost.me/i/73/1981088.jpg)

Comment: @faidam so it looks like a bug in the internals of ifx when resolving the underlying data types to the .net types. Are you using any uncommon data types in your data? Either way: this is an ifx bug.

Comment: @faidam if it was me, I would replace the "select *" with the individual column names - perhaps even adding them one at a time. It sounds like the ifx library doesn't like one of your columns - by introducing them one at a time you should be able to find which

Comment: @MarcGravell only varchars. Du you suggest that I use a different CSDK?

Comment: @MarcGravell I've tried one by one, same error. I'll try an other CSDK

Comment: @MarcGravell Is there a way to perform a select using a DataSet?

Comment: @fadam dataset still gets the data via the ado.net provider; if the ado.net provider is broken, it will still be broken no matter what you plan on doing with the data afterwards.

Comment: @MarcGravell when I used a "data grid view" and a "filled by" it worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

So the problem, I guess, was the version of the Framework. I downgraded to the 2.0 .net framework and it worked. I've tried it on two servers and it is fine!
I've also changed the CSDK I went from 3.5 to 4.1

@MarcGravell thank you man!